# Beginner: Vue Errors 'Vue is not defined'

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm just beginning to learn view and am practicing using it, but I keep getting the errors "vue was used before it was defined" and "Vue is not defined". Ive uploaded what I have in my html and my js file.

```js
var app = new Vue();

app({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    product: 'Socks'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue practice</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
  
  <div class="product-image">
    <img src="" />
  </div>

  <div class="product-info">
    <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
  </div>

</div> 

 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put those parameters into your Vue() constructor

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    product: 'Socks'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Vue practice</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
  
  <div class="product-image">
    <img src="" />
  </div>

  <div class="product-info">
    <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
  </div>

</div> 

 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i had it like that before I changed it and basically had the same errors, could it be my text editor? The errors I have now is 'Vue was used before it was defined'. 'app is assigned a value but never used', and 'Vue is not defined'.

Comment: Yes, those 'errors' are just warnings in your editor.
Your editor is only aware of the js file, not the fact that it is to be included in a page that has Vue defined (hence the first warning). To let your editor know that you are using Vue you need to add a reference to it at the top of your js file (for VS Code the referrence looks like this `/// <reference path="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js" />`)
The other warning is exactly as it says -  you have created a variable called app but haven't used it yet. 
You can safely ignoore both warnings if you like